# Is there possible to create training matrix for both RGB and Gray Scale images

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create training matrix for CNN.
Images are both RGB and Grey/scale.

To create something like 
`[ # of images, #features ]`

Image Size is :

`1024* 1024`

Following is my code:

```
from skimage.transform import rescale, resize
from skimage import io

features = np.empty((0,1024 * 1024), np.float32)
imagePath = directoyPath+"/"+ imageName
image = io.imread(imagePath)
print(image.shape)
flatFeatures = np.reshape(image,(1,1024*1024))
print(flatFeatures.shape)
features = np.append(features, flatFeatures, axis=0)
print(features.shape)
```

The problem is RGB shape is (1024,1024,3).

How i can feed the RGB and grey scale images to `features` matrix.

Comment: Do you want to include both RGB and Grayscale images to the training set at the same time.?

Comment: Yes, some images are black / white and some are RGB

Comment: You said you are trying to make a CNN. As far as I know, Both type images can't be used at the same time for that purpose.

Comment: alright, can you tell me if I create training matrix for RGB only? What would be the difference compared with Grey Scale?
Like  for gray scale the matrix shape is (0,1024*1024) what would be for RGB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you would have to feed in the RGB images after converting it into greyscale, you cannot pass images of different channels into a CNN, since RGB have 3 channels and grey scale images have 1 channel, specifying channels in the input layer of a CNN are necessary, it cannot be dynamic, so you have to make sure that you either have 3 channels or 1

for your purposes i would suggest you convert your grayscale images to RGB using `cvtColor(gray, color, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` the image wouldn't actually gain any color, but the number of channels in it would be 3, allowing you to pass both RGB and grayscale(technically RGB but still colorless) images together

Comment: can you tell me if I create a training matrix for RGB only? What would be the difference compared with Grey Scale? Like for gray scale the matrix shape is (0,1024*1024) what would be for RGB?

Comment: for starters the matrix shape for grayscale is (1,1024*1024)

Comment: in contrast rgb is (3,1024*1024) i think

Comment: Yes i have created matrix shape for this dimension. Can you tell me what would be the dimension for RGB training matrix.

Comment: ok thanks, can you share the link for creating the RGB training matrix for (3,1024*1024) matrix and filling.

Comment: i think you followed a MNIST tutorial, since you are flattening a 1024 by 1024 image, that is pretty useless, i suggest you dont flatten your images